# How can Change the value of my input dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript

*I'm building a simple Random Number Generator app, where I have a max value and min value as inputs, I've passed the values initially using HTML, but when I have my form displayed and I want to change the inputs values to other values to have another result, the initial values persist*

What do you think guys?

**My script file**

```
let maxNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("max").value);
let minNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("min").value);
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
const form = document.getElementById("form");


minNum = Math.ceil(minNum);
maxNum = Math.floor(maxNum);

//Onsubmit 
 function GetNumberSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    if(!maxNum || !minNum) {
        alert("Please enter Both value");
    }

     else if(maxNum && minNum ) {
        console.log(GetRandomNumber())
        result.value = GetRandomNumber();
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
    
}

function GetRandomNumber() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum +1 ) + minNum );
    return randomNumber;
}


form.addEventListener('submit', GetNumberSubmit);
```

***html***

```
<div class="game-container">
    <h1>Random number Generator</h1>
    <form id="form">
       <input type="text" 
              placeholder="" 
              id="result" value=""/>
        <div class="form-control-container">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="max">Max</label> 
                <input id="max" value="10"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="max">Min</label> 
                <input id="min" value="5"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button  class="submit-btn" id="button">Hit it</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work on your script part. The variables minNum and maxNum are only once requested. You should redefine them inside your function

```js
function GetNumberSubmit(e) {
    let maxNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("max").value);
    let minNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("min").value);
    minNum = Math.ceil(minNum);
    maxNum = Math.floor(maxNum);
    //...
}
```

And your GetRandomNumber function should take maxNum and minNum as arguments.

```js
function GetRandomNumber(maxNum, minNum) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Values persist because you defined the values for `maxNum` and `minNum` at the initial part of the script, the values are not updated inside the function definition. So the function always calculates with the inital value of the inputs. This wont update with the user input.

In order for the function to take the latest value, move `maxNum` and `minNum` definition to the function `GetNumberSubmit`

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
const form = document.getElementById("form");



//Onsubmit 
function GetNumberSubmit(e) {
  let maxNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("max").value);
  let minNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("min").value);
  minNum = Math.ceil(minNum);
  maxNum = Math.floor(maxNum);
  console.log(maxNum, minNum)
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!maxNum || !minNum) {
    alert("Please enter Both value");
  }

  else if (maxNum && minNum) {
    console.log(GetRandomNumber(maxNum, minNum))
    result.value = GetRandomNumber(maxNum, minNum);
  }
  else {
    return "";
  }

}

function GetRandomNumber(maxNum, minNum) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1) + minNum);
  return randomNumber;
}


form.addEventListener('submit', GetNumberSubmit);
```

```html
<div class="game-container">
  <h1>Random number Generator</h1>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="result" value="">
    <div class="form-control-container">
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="max">Max</label>
        <input id="max" value="10">
      </div>

      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="max">Min</label>
        <input id="min" value="5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="submit-btn" id="button">Hit it</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The number persist because of the value of you're variable so you can declare the inside your function (GetNumberSubmit) and put the other function(GetRandomNumber) and it will work :) .
Don't put your variable as a paramter in the GetRandomNumber because it dosn't will work because of the local scope of them in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I kinda get where you want to get at, but could you formulate differently? It's a little hard to read and follow